# Unable to pickle protobuf objects for parallelisation using ray in python

Tags: python, protocol-buffers, grpc, ray

We’re using grpc and protobuf objects as our communication method for a reinforcement learning project, Using python as a client and an external program as a server.
We’re currently in the process of trying to get multiple environments running in parallel to speed up training times, hence the use of ray.
However I am running into issues getting our existing communication methods to serialize properly for ray.remote etc.

This is the main error message that comes up:

```
“TypeError: cannot pickle ‘google.protobuf.pyext._message.MessageDescriptor’ object”
```

Any potential solutions or ideas? My python knowledge is lacking a little some i’m not exactly sure what the best way around this is.

Comment: What Ray version are you on?

Comment: I'm on ray version 2.2.0

Comment: I know nothing of Ray, but, there is the possibility of serialising the GPB objects to their own wireformat first? Pickling the byte array generated by GPB's own serialisation should take next to no time, I'd have thought. It's a two stage thing, but the second stage is very lightweight. Possibly Ray can be made to understand that pickling isn't actually required? That would be a bonus.

Comment: Looks like some Ray folks have picked up discussion on the discuss site, we should post the answer here once it's known https://discuss.ray.io/t/unable-to-pickle-protobuf-objects-for-parallelisation/9410

Comment: Python protobuf messages are not pickleable. You might consider converting to JSON before passing them across a process boundary.